# Is there any objective criterion to determine the adequate degree of polynomial approximations?

Tags: regression, approximation

I carry out a polynomial function approximation to a load duration curve (monotone decreasing function). I can approximate the load duration curve by using polynomial degrees from 4 to 12. I need an objective criterion to select the degree of polynomial considering a tradeoff between accuracy and included number of parameters in the function. Statistically, one can use adjusted R2 or information criterion. But these statistical criteria do not work because the residuals are nonlinear (not suitable for adjusted R2) and also I use least squares (do not have maximum likelihood value). Is there any other criterion to choose the adequate degree of polynomial from 4th to 12th degree?

[image: Scatter plot of residuals]

[image: Autocorrelation plot]

[image: QQ Plot of residuals]

Comment: The best criterion is not to use polynomials unless an underlying theory indicates they are appropriate (in which case the theory almost always tells you what degree to use), *especially* for monotonic regression.  It's unclear what "nonlinear" residuals could be, but it seems to mean they contra-indicate using least squares to make the fit.  If you could explain why you're trying to fit functions to your load duration, your readers might be able to make suggestions that help you improve your overall analysis.

Comment: SInce what is adequate is inherently subjective (it depends on your situation/purpose and your preferences), I'd have to say "no, there's no objective criterion". At least not without specifying more things up front.

Comment: @whuber According to Weierstrass Approximaton Theory, any continuous function can be approximated to any accuracy by a
polynomial of high enough degree. I came up with the idea of using mean absolute percentage error, the deviation of area under the curve from the actual area (corresponds to that year's electricity consumption) and the error in approximating highest demand. The best result is using 11th degree polynomial; however compared to a 5th degree polynomial the gain is not that much with respect to the number of parameters used. But this is an arbitrary decision not objective.

Comment: @Glen_b Although I can have a basis to compare the accuracy of approximations, I dont have a measure to compare gained accuracy w.r.t number of parameters used in polynomials.

Comment: @Dirk That is fine in theory and useless in practice.  The problem with polynomial approximations is that they can appear to fit data well but they change wildly in between the data points. At the very least, use a *maximum* error (the $L_\infty$ norm) rather than the mean so that you can get some control over those wild swings. Consider low-degree polynomial splines instead of polynomials.

Comment: @Dirk (on your comment to whuber) while you can approximate known functions with polynomials, that doesn't imply the properties of polynomials  *fitted to data* will all be desirable. You really should listen to whuber on that point (I'd give exactly the same advice... indeed I'd be surprised to find an experienced statistician that would say much different).  If you're looking for a measure that compares fit while accounting for parameters used, there are ways to do that. A good way is comparison on holdout data to compare out of sample predictive ability (e.g. via cross validation).  ...ctd

Comment: ctd ... Or you might use AIC or BIC or MDL all of which contain what can be viewed as penalty terms for number of parameters. You can look at (or indeed derive) AIC as an asymptotic approximation to -2log-likelihood adjusted for the bias of fitting via maximizing $\mathcal{L}$. You can derive BIC as an asymptotic approximation to -2log(posterior probability of the model), plus a constant. Other measures have adjustments as well.

Comment: @Glen_b I calculated the corrected AIC values as: 4th degree -130657, 5th degree -135543, 6th degree -136346, 7th degree  -141049, 8th degree -141251, 9th degree  -145316, 10 th degree  -145606, 11th degree -151349, 12th degree -151600. So, the adequate polynomial is the 12th degree polynomial.  However the performance of 12th degree approximation is not as good as the 11th degree polynomial for evaluating duration value of 1, i.e. f(1) (this is called the peak load). Estimation of peak loads is very important in energy economics.

Comment: @Glen_b In this respect, AICc does not help me for choosing an adequate model with respect to energy economics. Further, I will also forecast the functional parameters using SARIMA model for representing load duration curves of the next 10 year. So, approximate coeffiecients for the past 15 years and forecast for the next 10 year. If I have more parameters to forecast, I will cause more uncertainty due to the recursive approach of time series analysis. There will be forecasts dependent on forecasts. Still, I dont have any idea how to select the degree of polynomial in an objective way.

Comment: " However the performance of 12th degree approximation is not as good as the 11th degree polynomial for evaluating duration value of 1," --- So you already have a specific, important criterion! You can deal with the differing number of parameters on that via data splitting/cross-validation and choose whatever is best on out-of-sample prediction. If for some reason that's hard you need something that penalizes heavier, like BIC. ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... However, I'd again suggest you pay attention to whuber's comments. I'd *totally avoid* using more than degree 3 polynomials without very strong reasons (cubic splines will almost always do better than high degree polynomials). Degree 11 or 12 polynomials are a recipe for several kinds of disaster

Comment: @Glen_b Thx. Can you suggest me any introductory book or references so that I can refer to them ?

Comment: What kind of thing are you after? information on the issues with high degree polynomials?

Comment: @Glen_b I want to be able to objectively indicate the problems (if any) with polynomials of higher degree for approximation of any data. By whuber "the best criterion is not to use polynomials unless an underlying theory indicates they are appropriate (in which case the theory almost always tells you what degree to use". I am just after the corresponding methods.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "objectively indicate" there, nor what kind of methods you mean. Methods to do what?

Comment: @Glen_b You wrote that "I'd totally avoid using more than degree 3 polynomials without very strong reasons" and "Degree 11 or 12 polynomials are a recipe for several kinds of disaster". Similarly, I want to propose some reasons for using 5th degree polynomial approximations and indicate that the degrees higher than 5th degree may cause "disasters". I am trying to build an objective basis. That's why I asked for some references. Remark that AICc and BIC indicate that 12th degree polynomials are best; however 11th degree polynomials are better for predicting f(1).

Comment: On the other hand 5th degree polynomials are as good as in predicting f(1) w.r.t 11 degree polynomials. If I use 5th degree polynomials, I do not have to consider 6 more parameters to forecast in the next stage.  My case is a bit complicated. I thought I can indicate objectively why I use a 5th degree polynomial.

Comment: If you're using polynomials to *forecast* -- even if the data are really generated by polynomials -- then forecast error may be smaller by using a simpler model than the "true" polynomial order. (The same can be true of other models, but its relatively easy to get it with models that can "blow up" at the boundary)